# How can I return all nested objects using python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, elasticsearch

I wrote an Elastic query which will check the condition **(status="APPROVED")** and Gets all **approved_by** objects.

This is my index **(portfolio)**:

```
{
  "settings": {},
  "mappings": {
    "portfolio": {
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "lcase_ascii_normalizer"
        },
        "archived_at": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "approved_by": {
          "id": "text",
          "name":"text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I have 60 objects whose status are approved , so when i run the query it will show 60 objects,but in my case i am getting only one object(I debugged the code, total 60 objects are coming as expected, but still returning only single object), please help guys.

**My query:**

```
profiles = client.search(index='portfolio', doc_type='portfolio',
                  scroll='10m', size=1000,
                  body={
                      "query": {"match": {"status": "APPROVED"}}
                   })
sid = profiles['_scroll_id']
scroll_size = len(profiles['hits']['hits'])
while scroll_size > 0:
     for info in profiles['hits']['hits']:
         item = info['_source']
         approved_by_obj = item.get('approved_by')
         if approved_by_obj:
             return (jsonify({"approved_by": approved_by_obj}))
```

**Expected o/p format:**

```
{
    "approved_by": {
        "id": "system",
        "name": "system"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting only one result because you're **returning** from your loop, effectively breaking out of it completely.

So, instead of returning from it, append the found `approved_by_object` to a list of your choice and then return that 60-member list:

```py
profiles = client.search(index='portfolio', doc_type='portfolio',
                         scroll='10m', size=1000,
                         body={
                             "query": {"match": {"status": "APPROVED"}}
                         })

sid = profiles['_scroll_id']
scroll_size = len(profiles['hits']['hits'])

approved_hits_sources = []    # <-- add this

while scroll_size > 0:
    for info in profiles['hits']['hits']:
        item = info['_source']
        approved_by_obj = item.get('approved_by')
        if approved_by_obj:
            approved_hits_sources.append({"approved_by": approved_by_obj})  # <--- append and not return

return jsonify({"approved_hits_sources": approved_hits_sources})
```